# Java Code generation using wireframes

Tags: java, swing

I want to generate Java Swing Code by processing MS Visio created wireframes. Is there any tool which can support this?

Answer (score 1):

I know a company called Obeo that markets a tool called Acceleo that is specialized into model to text transformations.

Based upon various Eclipse technologies, it allows one to generate code from [DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language)/[DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_modeling).

They have a site allowing one to use already existing engines, as an example the [cinematic model](http://www.obeonetwork.org/overview/is-repository/cinematic-metamodel), which is precisely what you're looking for, I guess.

Unfortunatly, to use this tool (and in fact all tools in the generation domain, you'll have to transform your Visio diagram into an [XMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMI) one, which is not impossible.